# How to create calendar view in OpenERP?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

```
class lich(osv.osv):
    _name = "tt_lich" 
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Mã lịch trình',size=20,required=True),
       'date_start':fields.date('Ngày bắt đầu'),
       'date_stop':fields.date('Ngày kết thúc'),
    }
lich()
<record id="lichcalendar" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Lịch sản xuất</field>
            <field name="model">tt_lich</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <calendar date_start="date_start" date_stop="date_stop">
                        <group col="2">
                            <field name="name"/>
                        </group>
                    </calendar>
             </field>
        </record>
        <record id="action_lich" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Lịch sản xuất</field>
            <field name="res_model">tt_lich</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form,calendar</field>
        </record>
```

I try to create some calendar view but when when i put start date and stop date in form view then I move to calendar view and it show this error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide `color` attribute to the calendar and `date_start` and `date_stop` field to specify the datetime data-type. So change the data-type from date to datetime after than it will work fine.

Try with this code,

```
class lich(osv.osv):
    _name = "tt_lich" 
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Mã lịch trình',size=20,required=True),
        'date_start':fields.datetime('Ngày bắt đầu'),
        'date_stop':fields.datetime('Ngày kết thúc'),
    }


<record id="lichcalendar" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Lịch sản xuất</field>
    <field name="model">tt_lich</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <calendar string="Lịch sản xuất" color="name" date_start="date_start" date_stop="date_stop">
            <field name="name"/>       
        </calendar>
     </field>
</record>
```

For more help of [calendar view](https://doc.odoo.com/6.0/developer/2_6_views_events/views/calendar_view/)

Comment: Thanks for your help :)).Can u help me again ? "http://i.imgur.com/ofJybCT.jpg". How can i show label at right ? Thanks

Comment: how many field you used in calendar tag? and make that all field have a value in database. It seems like value is not present in database.

Comment: i have only 3 field (name,date_start,date_stop).I make all field have a value and it seem something wrong .If i fill field name with number like (1,2 or 3 ..) it only show check box with no label .if i fill with string no check box show.

Comment: strange, At right side label means color="name". so name has value than it should be display value for that.

Comment: I create a many2one field and make color ="many2one field" and it works fine now .Thanks for your help :))

Comment: Yes because generally color takes a many2one field. you may also take a look reference link in answer given and it will also work for char type. ;-)